# How to parse command output (docker log) through goaccess?

Tags: docker, logging

How to parse `docker logs` output / tail output through goaccess? When I do:

```
docker container logs mycontainer > logs
```

and then `goaccess -f logs` it works perfectly, but if I do `docker logs --tail all mycontainer | goaccess -` it doesn't work :( but in the manual  you can do this via tailing command: https://goaccess.io/man

```
tail -f access.log | goaccess -
```

Pls help :( I think the problem is that the native tailing differs from docker's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? I got an error suggesting that the log format wasn't correct:

```
Fatal error has occurred
Error occured at: src/goaccess.c - set_curses - 1394
No time format was found on your conf file.
```

When I edited `/etc/goaccess.conf` (i.e. uncommented/selected `time-format`, `date-format` and `log-format`) the `docker logs mycontainer | goaccess -` command works as expected.

As an aside, for my `nginx` proxy inside my docker container, I had to set my `log_format` as follows:

```
log-format %v %h %^ %^ [%d:%t %^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u"
```